# Which hook if user profile information is updated?

Tags: hooks, profiles

I'm looking for the hook that fires when a user's information are updated. Specifically, I want to update a post with the value of a custom profile field (in my example `info`) everytime that user's profile is updated.

I tried the `profile_update` hook, but it doesn't seem to fire:

```
add_action( 'profile_update', 'add_info_to_post' );
function add_info_to_post( $user_id ) {

        $info=get_user_meta($user_id,'info',true);

        //get all items of that user
        $args=array(
                'author' => $user_id,
                'post_type' => 'item',
        );

        $items=get_posts($args);            
        foreach ($items as $item){
        update_post_meta($item->ID,'user_info',$info);
        }
}
```

Any suggestions how to make this work?

EDIT:
Maybe I should mention that I access the users' profile pages through the backend..

Comment: In your code the function name and the function you have in the add_action don't match.

Comment: right! corrected

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Codex: Plugin API - Action Reference - profile_update](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/profile_update):

> **Note:** This hook is not used on user edit/profile pages. To hook into the admin's user edit pages, use the hook [edit_user_profile_update](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/edit_user_profile_update) which is located in [`/wp-includes/user-edit.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src//wp-includes/user-edit.php#L0) instead.

From [Codex: Plugin API - Action Reference - edit_user_profile_update](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/edit_user_profile_update):

> This hook only triggers when a user is viewing another user's profile page (not their own). If you want to apply your hook to ALL profile pages (including the current user) then you also need to use the [personal_options_update](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/personal_options_update) hook.